# How to preserve newline characters in CSH when storing in a variable or echo

Tags: python, echo, csh

I have a `python` script which is getting called from a `csh` script ( I can not use `bash`). The python script prints out string with the newline characters and I am storing the output in a csh variable. However, as soon I store it in a variable, I am losing all the newline characters. Below are the scripts:

python script (pcmd.py)

```
def main(op):
    if op == "h": # print help
        # below newline character is getting lost
        print ("Help first line\n second line.")
    else:  # print and later execute csh commands
        print ("setenv SOME_ENV_VAR 123; setenv ANOTHER asd")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

csh script (pcmd.csh)

```
# store the py script in a variable
set pcmd="./pcmd.py $*"
# store the output of the first eval command
set output=`eval "$pcmd"`
# if output contains setenv, eval the output (csh commands)
if ( "$output" =~ *setenv* ) then
    eval "${output}"
else # otherwise, print the output
    echo "${output}"  # Issue : losing newline chars, tried echo -e too but of no avail
```

execution

```
pcmd.csh h
expects: Help first line
second line.

actual: Help first line second line.  # missing newline character
```

Can someone point out the missing bit in the scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how csh behaves. From its man page:

> Command substitution is indicated by a command enclosed in ``'.  The
> output from such a command is broken into separate words at blanks,
> tabs and newlines, and null words are discarded.  The output is
> variable and command substituted and put in place of the original
> string.
>
> Command substitutions inside double quotes (`"') retain blanks and
> tabs; only newlines force new words.  The single final newline does
> not force a new word in any case.  It is thus possible for a command
> substitution to yield only part of a word, even if the command outputs
> a complete line.
>
> By default, the shell since version 6.12 replaces all newline and
> carriage return characters in the command by spaces.  If this is
> switched off by unsetting csubstnonl, newlines separate commands as
> usual.

The last time I used csh was the mid 1980's. I don't believe what you're trying to do is possible. Csh is a horrible shell. Even worse than POSIX shells like Bash. Even if you can't use Bash is there some reason you can't use /bin/sh? Or, better yet, a modern sane shell like Fish or Elvish?

One (partial) solution is to use double-quotes and array capture:

```
set output=("`$pcmd`")
```

That will make `output` an array var where each element is a line. You can then iterate over the array to construct a string where each element (line) is separated by a newline. Note that I omitted the `eval` because in your example it isn't necessary and is exceedingly dangerous. Note that I called this a "partial" solution because contiguous newlines are treated as if a single newline was present.

Comment: thank you, it is old legacy script to set then environment variables and I am afraid I can not use any other shell ( I wish I could have).

Comment: @DDStackoverflow See my update to this answer for one possible way to solve your problem. But, again, if you're allowed to modify that Csh script I fail to see why you can't convert it to a saner shell.

Comment: this did not work I got the error on `foreach` loop. However, I figured out a workaround where I am doing all the gymnastics in python script like, instead of printing `Help first ...` I am printing `"echo \"Help first line\"; echo \"second...\""`
which can be evaluated in the wrapper script. thanks for your response and description :)